# `npm publish` and `npm install` fail depending on `.npmrc` syntax used

Tags: node.js, npm

## Current Behavior:

I am attempting to configure a project to install dependencies from NPM. I will be publishing the project to GitHub Packages as a private package. If I use this syntax in my project's `.npmrc`:

```
@my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

I can install dependencies from NPM using `npm install` on my local machine. However, I cannot publish to GitHub Packages using `npm publish`. NPM informs me that I'm not authenticated. If I use this syntax in my project's `.npmrc`:

```
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/my-org/
```

I can publish using `npm publish`, but I cannot install dependencies with `npm install`. NPM informs me that it's trying to install dependencies from GitHub Packages, rather than NPM.

## Expected Behavior:

Based on my reading, both syntaxes should be compatible with `npm install` and `npm publish`. However, it appears I can only use one or the other, based on my intended use.

## Steps To Reproduce:

1. Install Node `v15.7.0` and NPM `7.4.3` via [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).
2. Log in to GitHub Packages with the command:

   ```sh
   npm login --scope=@my-org --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
   ```
3. Check our `~/.npmrc` file in our home folder. It should read:

   ```
   @my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
   //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<auth-token-used-for-login>
   ```
4. Create project with the following `package.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "name": "@my-org/my-package",
     "description": "A test.",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
     },
     "repository": {
       "type": "git",
       "url": "https://github.com/my-org/my-package.git"
     },
     "keywords": ["example"],
     "author": "Me",
     "license": "ISC",
     "bugs": {
       "url": "https://github.com/my-org/my-package/issues"
     },
     "homepage": "https://github.com/my-org/my-package",
     "dependencies": {
       "bootstrap": "^4.5.2"
     }
   }
   ```
5. Add the following `.npmrc` to our project:

   ```
   @my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
   ```
6. Run `npm install`. Installation should succeed.
7. Run `npm publish`. Receive the following error:

   ```sh
   npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
   npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
   npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /Users/my-user/.npm/_logs/2021-01-28T20_19_55_974Z-debug.log
   ```
8. Change the project `.npmrc` to:

   ```
   registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/my-org/
   ```
9. Run `npm publish`. Publishing should succeed.
10. `rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json` in project.
11. Run `npm install`. Receive following error:

    ```
    npm ERR! code E401
    npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
    npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
    npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
    npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
    npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
    npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
    npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
    npm ERR!     npm login

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/my-user/.npm/_logs/2021-01-28T20_38_20_711Z-debug.log
    ```

## Environment:

- OS:

  - MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
  - MacOS Big Sur 11.1
- Node: 15.7.0
- npm: 7.4.3

## Things I've tried

### Using `publishConfig`

Unfortunately, `publishConfig` doesn't fix the issue. It also doesn't address that the two `.npmrc` syntaxes produce different results.

### Project `.npmrc` `authToken`

NPM's documentation states there is no need to include the `authToken` in the project `.npmrc`. Authenticating with `npm login` and storing the `authToken` in the global `~/.npmrc` should be sufficient.

## Workaround

### Using the `--registry` command line flag

I've found a workaround until the NPM bug affecting this issue is resolved. When using the following project `.npmrc` syntax:

```
@my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

If I run `npm publish --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/`, I can publish successfully. In addition, I can install dependencies without issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update (May 30, 2021)

This has been fixed in NPM `7.5.3` and above.

### Original answer (April 20, 2021)

This has been confirmed as a bug on NPM `7.x`. The team is currently working to fix the bug with their [GitHub Pull Request #2602](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/2602). Until this bug fix has been released, the best recommendation is to do one of the workarounds listed below.

### Workaround 1: `--registry` command line flag

When running `npm publish`, add the `--registry` flag. This flag enables developers to specify the registry they're aiming to publish to, overriding `.npmrc` or `package.json` configurations. For the example listed in my question, the project `.npmrc` should contain:

```
@my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

Publishing will succeed when initiated by running:

```sh
npm publish --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

### Workaround 2: Dummy token for default registry

According to [npm developer wraithgar's comment on this bug's GitHub issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2567#issuecomment-772085171), you can use a dummy token for the default NPM registry to workaround this issue. In our project's `.npmrc`, add the following line:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=dummy
```

The full project `.npmrc` should contain:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=dummy
@my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

In the question, neither of the project `.npmrc` syntax's we've tried to use has designated a registry, because NPM's documentation states we don't have to. The documentation states that it'll check our global `~/.npmrc` if there isn't one in our project `.npmrc`. The bug in NPM is causing NPM to check if a project `.npmrc` has designated a registry before it'll attempt to authenticate. In [wraithgar's own words](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2567#issuecomment-772082206):

> What happens is that currently the cli is only looking for your configured "registry" setting when seeing if you have logged in. So the temporary solution is either to override that setting (as you were doing by passing --registry), OR to add a token for the default (npm) registry so that the check for a token does not fail. The check is only looking for the presence of a token in the config, it's not validating it (that of course will happen when and if it is used during an actual request), so putting a dummy value in will stop the error until that PR lands.

After adding the dummy token, running `npm publish` and `npm install` should both succeed.

Comment: I confirm this answer as correct. With npm 7.x.x... I've used publish--registry=http://my-registry:4873/ ... It wasn't necessary for me to add @my-org before my registry on my .npmrc... thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error. First thing I have fixed was npm version to > 7.5.3 as suggested in accepted answer, but no luck, same error:

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

After trying all of advised workarounds it still was giving the same output. Finally I found the reason: I forgot to add the scope in the package.json "name" property, so problem was solved by changing

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  ...
```

to

```
{
  "name": "@my-org/my-package",
  ...
```

Answer (score -3):

I found 2 problems in steps from 1 to 7.

1. in step 4, did you try to add the field below in the `package.json`

```
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  }
```

2. in `.npmrc` in step 5, I didn't see `//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<auth-token-used-for-login>`, remember `//` is not the comment. `;` or `#` are for comments. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/npmrc#comments

Comment: Unfortunately, `publishConfig` doesn't fix the issue. It also doesn't address that the two `.npmrc` syntaxes produce different results. Additionally, NPM's documentation states there is no need to include the `authToken` in the project `.npmrc`. Authenticating with `npm login` and storing the `authToken` in the global `~/.npmrc` should be sufficient.

Comment: Those are the only 2 difference between your configuration and mine and mine works (We have the same use case). Another difference is in my .npmrc, there are _password, username, email, always-auth fields, I doubt those affects.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to test. Testing both on my end didn't end up working. Part of what I'm looking for is a canonical answer, since there doesn't seem to be a reason why the syntax I'm using _isn't_ working.