# How to login to the gitHub npm registry through .npmrc file?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, github-actions

In view of the automation, through `.yml` file, of the publication of an `npm` package, I am attempting to login to the github registry through `.npmrc` file instead of the usual, interactive, `npm login` command. However, until now, I have not been able to do it.

If I type, in my console, from the root folder of my Nodejs project:

```
npm login
username: myName
password: xyz
npm publish
```

I succed in publishing my package.

However, if I create an `.npmrc` file containing

```
@myOrg:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:username=myName
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=xyz
```

and execute the command

```
npm publish
```

I get the error:

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://npm.pkg.github.com/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

Notice that `xyz` is the same secret value in both attempts either interactive or non-interactive of logging in.

The `package.json` file of my project contains the entries:

```
{
    "name": "@myOrg/myRepo",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "...",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/myOrg/myRepo.git"
    },
    "publishConfig": {
        "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
    }
...
}
```

I suppose that if I am able to login to the registry from console through `.npmrc` file, I will also be able to automate the publication through an opportune `.yml` file by creating the `.npmrc` file at runtime and injecting the secret value, so that, my problem is:

> how to log in non-interactively through an `.npmrc` file?

Comment: Please compare with https://stackoverflow.com/q/65945592/367456 - `~/.npmrc` might be interfeering. For Github in specific see https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry

Comment: Thank you very much @hakre. Yes, I had a global `~/.npmrc` with an old, no-longer valid, access token. I don't really know when and how I created such a global `~/.npmrc`. However, the users should be aware that such a global `~/.npmrc` file is required anyway: the access token is not read from the local `.npmrc` file even after removing the global `~/.npmrc` file. This happens at least in my configuration: `node 18.15.0` and `npm 9.7.2`